# Get first value from a list of dictionaries in pandas data frame column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
id       photos
001      [{'medium':'https:blablabla1',
           'xl':'something1',
           's':'anotherthing1'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla2',
           'xl':'something2',
           's':'anotherthing2'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla3',
           'xl':'something3',
           's':'anotherthing3'}]
002      [{'medium':'https:blablabla4',
           'xl':'something4',
           's':'anotherthing4'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla5',
           'xl':'something5',
           's':'anotherthing5'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla6',
           'xl':'something6',
           's':'anotherthing6'}]
003      [{'medium':'https:blablabla7',
           'xl':'something7',
           's':'anotherthing7'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla8',
           'xl':'something8',
           's':'anotherthing8'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla9',
           'xl':'something9',
           's':'anotherthing9'}]
```

The second **photos** column contains **a list of dictionaries**.
What I'd like to get is the value of the first key:value pair in the list.

The desired output should look like this:

```
id       image_url
001      https:blablabla1
002      https:blablabla4
003      https:blablabla7
```

I have figured out how to do it if it is a single list of dicts. Like this:

```
dicts_list = [{'medium':'https:blablabla1',
           'xl':'something1',
           's':'anotherthing1'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla2',
           'xl':'something2',
           's':'anotherthing2'},
         {'medium':'https:blablabla3',
           'xl':'something3',
           's':'anotherthing3'}]

# Access the first value of the first dict in a list 
list(dicts_list[0].values())[0]

#output
'https:blablabla1'
```

I've achieved this so far (which is obviously wrong):

```
v = list()
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    photo = rows['photos']
    v.append(photo[0])

# output
['[', '[']
```

The idea is to put the first values into a list and then add it back to the original data frame.
I can't figure out how to extend it into a pandas dataframe.

**NOTE** 
Based on @daren-thomas answer, I figured out that the dictionary I was referring to in my data is a string representation of dictionary. So to convert this column into a dictionary, refer to this code:

```
import ast
df.photos = df.photos.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Comment: Getting the first dict in a list is fine but the first key in a dict? I know Python 3.6 onwards there's guaranteed insertion order... but is it guaranteed that each dict will have it's keys inserted in order? So would you be okay with getting the first dict and first arbitrary key in a dict? Or in your example should it always be `medium`?

Comment: @Orenshi it should always be `medium`. It should be okay to get the first arbitrary key in a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function on each row like this:

```
df['image_url'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.photos[0]['medium'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   id                                         photos         image_url
0  001  [{u's': u'anotherthing1', u'medium': u'https:b...  https:blablabla1
1  002  [{u's': u'anotherthing4', u'medium': u'https:b...  https:blablabla4
2  003  [{u's': u'anotherthing7', u'medium': u'https:b...  https:blablabla7
```

Now, if you don't like the `photos` column, you can just drop it...

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: ('string indices must be integers, not str', u'occured at index 0']. I'm using Python 2.7. @daren-thomas

Comment: @mahf_i, what is the type of your `photos` column? I was assuming it's a dictionary, but from your error message it seems it's a string representation of a dictionary? That would also explain your very weird output (`['[', '[']`) in your question...

Comment: It's a string column @daren-thomas

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. If your column or `Series` is a list of dicts like below:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([[{'medium':'https:blablabla1',
...   'xl':'something1',
...   's':'anotherthing1'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla2',
...   'xl':'something2',
...   's':'anotherthing2'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla3',
...   'xl':'something3',
...   's':'anotherthing3'}],
... [{'medium':'https:blablabla4',
...   'xl':'something4',
...   's':'anotherthing4'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla5',
...   'xl':'something5',
...   's':'anotherthing5'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla6',
...   'xl':'something6',
...   's':'anotherthing6'}],
... [{'medium':'https:blablabla7',
...   'xl':'something7',
...   's':'anotherthing7'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla8',
...   'xl':'something8',
...   's':'anotherthing8'},
... {'medium':'https:blablabla9',
...   'xl':'something9',
...   's':'anotherthing9'}]])
>>> s
0    [{'medium': 'https:blablabla1', 'xl': 'somethi...
1    [{'medium': 'https:blablabla4', 'xl': 'somethi...
2    [{'medium': 'https:blablabla7', 'xl': 'somethi...
dtype: object
>>> s.apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(pd.Series).medium
0    https:blablabla1
1    https:blablabla4
2    https:blablabla7
Name: medium, dtype: object
```

Not sure if there's a more elegant solution. But hope this helps!

-- Edit --

Just as a side note, I know heavy usage of `apply` is frowned upon in the `pandas` community. Especially if you have very LARGE `DataFrame`s...  you'll see some performance issues.

I can't really think of a `vectorized` solution. But if your dataset isn't too big, I think this should do the trick.